# Seeking help with the interpretation of this seal. Can anyone help me?

Tags: translation, meaning, characters, character-identification, seal

**This seal is located in the lower left corner of my free hand brushwork painting and I suspect that it could contain the name of the artist. All help will be appreciated.[image]**

Answer (score 2):

Hua Zhang, "张化", a Sichuan-born Chinese artist. His art name is "青城石翁". "青城" is a mountain located in Sichuan Province, and "石翁" is a commonly used art name, meaning "stone old man", implying ones toughness and integrity. Here is another art of him, and you can see the seal on it.[image]

Comment: I'd like to know more about this artist and the painting that you posted but can't find anything under "Hua Zhang" or "Qingcheng Shiweng".

Comment: Here is his personal information (in Chinese) [link](//61.134.53.202:81/refbook/detail.aspx?recid=R2006050480002704&db=CRFD). And this is his another piece of work (in an auction site).[link](http://haohan.69ys.com/pre/detail/164707#anchor)

Comment: I was successful at opening up the auction link but not the biography link. It appears that his work is confined locally and is not very well known, averaging from $300 to $500. Thanks to all of the Forum contributors for your help especially Kai.

Answer (score 0):

I think on the top right side is 青, it means blue green in Chinese.

The down right side is 城, it means city.

The down left side is 羽, it means feather.

Comment: it might be 石翁.

Comment: Although greatly appreciated, the responses thus far are conflicting to say the least and has me confused.  Are there any other opinions?

Comment: @TangHo I think that you're right. It's 石翁.